# What is the probability of the following problem?

Tags: probability

There are 6 people: A, B, C, D, E, F and 4 free seats. What is the probability that person A will take a seat?

Comment: Any thought?  I assume you want us to assume that the relevant probabilities are uniform.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Out of 6 people in the group, pick 2 to stay and the rest will sit. Picking anyone can only happen at first try or at the second try, since you are picking 2 people. How many ways to pick with $A$? Without $A$? What is the probability $A$ ends up picked?

Comment: I think there are $5*4$ ways to not pick A. Since there are $6*5$ ways to pick 2 of them, we get that there are $6*5-5*4$ ways to pick A. Am I right? So the probability to pick A is $\frac{10}{30}$.

Comment: There are $5 \times 4!=120$ ways to not pick $A.$ But the total number of ways is $\binom {6} {4} \times 4!.$ So the required probability is $\frac {\binom 6 4 \times 4! - 120} {\binom 6 4 \times 4!} = \frac {10} {15} = \frac {2} {3}.$

Comment: I don't know that notation, if you can explain me what it means. Also, why the total is not $6*5$? For the first there are $6$ ways and for the second $6-1$, so $6*5$.

Comment: Do you know $\binom {m} {n}$ notation?

Comment: I know that it can be a $2\times 1$ matrix, but other than that, no.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let the be a lottery with $6$ lots among which $4$ give a prize.

If  person A buys a lot then what is his chance to win a prize?

Comment: It's $\frac{4}{6}$ obviously.

Comment: That is the correct. Now do it with $6$ seats of which $4$ are free. A,B,C,D,E,F all choose a seat.

Answer (score 1):

Another method.

**Total:** there are $P(6,4)=\frac{6!}{2!}$ ways for four people to sit.

**Favorable (with $A$):** $A$ can sit on any of the ${4\choose 1}=4$ seats. There are $P(5,3)=\frac{5!}{2!}$ ways other three seats can be occupied. So, in total: $4\cdot \frac{5!}{2!}$ ways.

Hence, the required probability is:
$$\frac{\frac{5!}{2!}\cdot 4}{\frac{6!}{2!}}=\frac23.$$
Note: $C(n,m)={n\choose m}=\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$ is a [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) and $P(n,m)=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$ is a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).

Answer (score 1):

$A$ will either be one of the $4$ people who take seats, or one of the $2$ people who don't.